# Comparison of meaning: Should vs Need

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recently saw the following sentence in a recruitment ad:

> '9-to-5 employees' need not apply

It's important to say that English is not my mother tongue, and maybe that's why something in the sentence did not sound good to me, because then I was told that the sentence was correct.

I thought that better options would be:

> 9-to-5 employees should not apply

or

> 9-to-5 employees need to not apply

Is there a difference in meaning between the three sentences?

Is the original sentence correct?

Comment: This use of _need_ is a semi-modal one. I.e, _need not_ means _must not_. The subject of _need not apply_ is being told not to apply. _Men need not apply_ means _Women only_, and vice versa.

Comment: It's understatement: Don't bother to come in on Monday = You're fired.

Comment: @John Lawler: In this case, "need not" doesn't mean "must not".  It means they are free to apply, but will just be wasting their time since they won't be considered.

Comment: "Need not", in this sense, is idiomatic.  Basically, as jamesqf states, it means that going against the advice is wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

When *need* is used as an auxiliary verb, it means that you're under obligation or necessity to do something. Adding *not* reverses this, it means you're *not* required to perform the action.  [M-W says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/need):

> be under necessity or obligation to
> *you need not answer*

"need not" is often used somewhat idiomatically to mean that not only is there no requirement, there's no point in performing the specified action. When it says "9-5 employees need not apply", they're saying that they've already decided not to accept applications from these employees, so they'd be wasting their time applying.

"should not" is either a command or strong suggestion, depending on the context. So if they say

> 9-5 employees should not apply

it means that the applications might not be totally forbidden, they would prefer that they not apply.

"need to not" is a stronger prohibition. It means that *not* performing the action is a requirement. It's very similar to "must not".